# Snowflake - Escape backslash and double quotes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data file in a BLOB and I am trying to create an external table from it. Here's how the file looks in a text editor:

```
"ABC"|"123"|"ID1"
"XYZ"|"456"|"ID2"
```

When I create an external table with a pipe as the delimiter and then query the individual columns, I see these values:

```
value:c1|value:c2|value:c3
"\"ABC\"" "\"123\"" "\"ID1\""
"\"XYZ\"" "\"345\"" "\"ID2\""
```

Is there something that I need to add to the `field_optionally_enclosed_by` option? I am easily able to do

```
select replace(value:c1,'\\"'),replace(value:c2,'\\"'),replace(value:c3,'\\"') from testable
```

and this gives me back

```
value:c1|value:c2|value:c3
"ABC" "123" "ID1"
"XYZ" "345" "ID2"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying "you have data in a single column that looks like `"ABC"|"123"|"ID1"` and the next row is `"XYZ"|"456"|"ID2"` and when you export this a file you would like those three values to be separate values, not just a single value? And that output format is using pipes, thus in your examples you have 3 columns headers defined, by only a single column, which has the old pipes stripped?

Comment: In the "input" always 3 wide or is it dynamic per row?

Comment: Basically I am trying to read a csv file delimited by pipes and would like to create an external table on top of it using different options to get rid of backslash and doublequotes

Comment: Input always has 3 columns. Do you know how would you do it with create external table?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below and see if it helps, it works in my test:

```
create or replace external table external_table 
 with location = @test.ericlin_s3_stage/t1/
 auto_refresh = true
 REFRESH_ON_CREATE = true
 FILE_FORMAT = (
    TYPE=CSV 
    COMPRESSION=NONE 
    REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE 
    FIELD_DELIMITER = '|' 
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\'
  );
```

```
select 
    value:c1, value:c2, value:c3 
from external_table;

+----------+----------+----------+
| VALUE:C1 | VALUE:C2 | VALUE:C3 |
|----------+----------+----------|
| "ABC"    | "123"    | "ID1"    |
| "XYZ"    | "456"    | "ID2"    |
+----------+----------+----------+


select 
    value:c1::string as c1, 
    value:c2::string as c2, 
    value:c3::string as c3
from external_table;

+-----+-----+-----+
| C1  | C2  | C3  |
|-----+-----+-----|
| ABC | 123 | ID1 |
| XYZ | 456 | ID2 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: That's not the problem. Data is in files on azure and it needs to be read using external tables concept of snowflake

Comment: I setup using external table, have updated my answer.

Comment: That did not help as now it doesn’t shows any data at all.

Comment: Can you please share how you created the table, i.e. the table DDL?

Comment: The exact same thing that you pasted. I copied it as is.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always fixed width, and you are want independent values for writting to the external table, then [SPLIT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split.html) and a nested select could help here:

```
SELECT
    get(s,0) as a,
    get(s,1) as b,
    get(s,2) as c
FROM (
    SELECT split(column1,'|') as s
    FROM VALUES
        ('"ABC"|"123"|"ID1"'),
        ('"XYZ"|"456"|"ID2"')
);
```

gives:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ""ABC"" | ""123"" | ""ID1"" |
| ""XYZ"" | ""456"" | ""ID2"" |

this look funning because the output layer has escaped the inner double quotes.  So you could use TRIM to drop those:

```
SELECT 
    trim(get(s,0),'"') as a,
    trim(get(s,1),'"') as b,
    trim(get(s,2),'"') as c
FROM (
    SELECT split(column1,'|') as s
    FROM VALUES
        ('"ABC"|"123"|"ID1"'),
        ('"XYZ"|"456"|"ID2"')
);
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | ID1 |
| XYZ | 456 | ID2 |

and if you dislike the sub-select you can use [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html)

```
SELECT 
    trim(split_part(column1,'|',0),'"') as a,
    trim(split_part(column1,'|',1),'"') as b,
    trim(split_part(column1,'|',2),'"') as c
FROM VALUES
    ('"ABC"|"123"|"ID1"'),
    ('"XYZ"|"456"|"ID2"')
;
```